# Faker seed data coding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker, bloc.io

I’m a new rails student working on a project that has a user login, each user has one list and each list has many items.  Items are nested under lists in my routes.

I’m having a few issues.  My code below loads one user and one list for that user, but fails to load items for the list. My thought was to get this to work first, but in the end I wanted to have 5 users, each with one list and 15 items on each list all created by faker.  Any help is appreciated.

```
require 'faker'

# Create an admin user
admin = User.new(
  name:     'Admin User',
  email:    'admin@example.com',
  password: 'helloworld'
)
admin.skip_confirmation!
admin.save!

# Create List
1.times do
  List.create(
    user: admin,
    title: 'Admin List'
  )
end

# Create Items
15.times do
  Item.create(
    list: 'Admin List',
    name: Faker::Company.bs
  )
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
puts "#{List.count} lists created"
puts "#{Item.count} items created"
```

This is the full error

```
heidi-golds-imac:blocitoff dale$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: List(#70281090559180) expected, got    String(#70281054267240)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:216:in  `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:12:in `replace'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-  4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `list='
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in    assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:557:in `init_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:280:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/Users/dale/code/blocitoff/db/seeds.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/dale/code/blocitoff/db/seeds.rb:21:in `times'
/Users/dale/code/blocitoff/db/seeds.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties- 4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top  (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Items Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_list

  def create
    @item = @list.items.build(params.require(:item).permit(:name))

    unless @item.save
      flash[:error] = "There was an error. Please try again."
    end

    redirect_to @list
  end

  private

  def find_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end
end
```

Lists Controller

```
 class ListsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :authenticate_user! # users must be signed in before any     lists_controller method

  def show
    @list = current_user.list
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
     @list = current_user.build_list(params.require(:list).permit(:title,  :body))
     if @list.save
       flash[:notice] = "List was saved."
       redirect_to @list
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end

  def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
     @list = List.find(params[:id])
     if @list.update_attributes(params.require(:list).permit(:title, :body))
       flash[:notice] = "List was updated."
       redirect_to @list
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are assigning the list to the item by name rather than by reference. In the block of code where you create your list, you need to assign that to a variable:

list = List.create...,

Then, when creating your item, you need to do this:

Item.create(list: list....

You were using the title of the list, where it was looking for a list object.

Answer (score 2):

Try to correct the following code:

```
# Create Items
15.times do
  Item.create(
    list: 'Admin List'
    name: Faker::Company.bs
  )
end
```

Just add a comma after list: 'Admin List'
If this doesn't resolve the issue please post the complete error message and specify the line on which you are getting the error.

Comment: Comma, didn't resolve, but now a new error.  I've edited above with comma and full new error.

Comment: Comma resolved the error which you posted previously. This is a new error. I suppose your line 21 is either 1.times or 15.times which is throwing an error in the .times. So try and change it. If the line differs specify which is line 21.